# Bar Y value in MPAndroid Chart

Tags: android, charts

I use the `MPandroid` Chart lib from github, this is the lib link [MPANDROID](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my app to draw some charts, but the problem is the height of the bar, I had **YValue1 = 81**, **YValue2 = 97**, **YValue3 = 91**, **YValue = 86** but the bars are very small !!

link of image

[image]

```
private void setBarChart(BarChart mChart, DashboardMCOP mcop, DashboardMCOM mcom)
    {
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
            mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(100);
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
           mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);  
        IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart,context );
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
        xAxis.setLabelCount(7);    
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);    
        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setEnabled(false);  
        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setEnabled(false);
         XYMarkerView mv = new XYMarkerView(context, xAxisFormatter);
        mv.setChartView(mChart); // For bounds control
        mChart.setMarker(mv); // Set the marker to the chart
        mChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
        setDataBar(mChart, mcop, mcom);

    }
```

my function to set Data in the bar chart

```
 private void setDataBar(BarChart mChart, DashboardMCOP mcop, DashboardMCOM mcom)
    {
        ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        int id = mChart.getId();

        String viewName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
       if(viewName.equalsIgnoreCase("barchartMCOM1")) {
            if(mcom != null) {
                yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0, mcom.getTreat()));
                yVals1.add(new BarEntry(1, mcom.getContract()));
            }

        }     
        BarDataSet set1 = null;
                set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");

            set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.rgb("#FF0000"));

            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
            dataSets.add(set1);

            BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
            data.setValueTextSize(10f);
            data.setBarWidth(0.9f);
            data.setValueFormatter(new MyAxisValueFormatter());
            mChart.setFitBars(true);
            mChart.setData(data);
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting min value for YAxis. Try using setAxisMinimum for Y axis and set it to zero. your bar height should increase correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I update the lib from github, then I use the sample BarChartFragment to reseolve the issue, this is my code for everyone who face the same problem in the futur :

```
private void setBarChart(BarChart mChart, DashboardMCOP mcop, DashboardMCOM mcom)
    {
        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        mv.setChartView(mChart); // For bounds control
        mChart.setMarker(mv);
        mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(100);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        IAxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart,context );

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
        xAxis.setLabelCount(7);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setEnabled(false);

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();

        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
        leftAxis.setEnabled(true);
        leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);




        mChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
        setDataBar(mChart, mcop, mcom);


    }
```

for **SetDataBar** is not changead !